# how to change QLabel to QCombobox when clicked

Tags: qt

I need a suggestion for making a QLabel to change as an editable comobox when user clicked it . similar like androidians.
i am planning to override the QLabel mousPress and show QComboBox while hiding the QLable.
is it right ..?

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is correct. Another way you could do it is by using just a combo box and setting a stylesheet to it, so that the borders, the background and the arrow is hidden when it's not selected:

```
QComboBox:!focus{background-color: transparent; border: 0px;}
QComboBox::drop-down:!focus {border-width: 0px;}
```

Comment: Yeah! best for avoiding a creation  of a class to override QComboBox