# Change QLabel to QCombobox in QStyledItemDelegate after click on QLabel

Tags: pyqt5

I need to change a `Qlabel` to a `Qcombobox` in a `QStyledItemDelegate`. But when I click on my label the combobox appears in the last visible row of the `QTableView`. 
I've tried to get `currentIndex`form the underlying table and to get the source of the click by `sender().objectName ()`. Both is correct, but independent how I try to set the row, the combo is still on the wrong row (the last). The solution in [Solution by CSS](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940002/how-to-change-qlabel-to-qcombobox-when-clicked) doesn't work for me.

How can I set the selected row in a delegate to a specific row to replace the widget?

working example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QItemDelegate, QLabel, QStyledItemDelegate, QComboBox, QAbstractItemView, QTextEdit, \
    QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow, QWidget, QApplication, QTableView
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, QModelIndex, QEvent, QVariant, QAbstractTableModel, QCoreApplication

class ClickLabel(QLabel):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()
        QLabel.mousePressEvent(self, event)

class dateDelegate2(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super (dateDelegate2, self).__init__ (parent)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if (
            isinstance(self.parent(), QAbstractItemView)
            and self.parent().model() is index.model()
        ):
            self.parent().openPersistentEditor(index)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QLabel(parent)

        self.dateValue = QLabel()
        self.dateValue.setFixedHeight(160)
        self.dateValue.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self.dateValue.setEnabled(False)
        self.dateValue.setStyleSheet ("QTextEdit{ border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; border-color: gray; color: blue; font-size: 12px }");

        self.itemValue = ClickLabel()
        self.itemValue.setFixedHeight(200)
        self.itemValue.setStyleSheet ("QLabel{ border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; border-color: gray; color: blue; font: bold; font-size: 14px  }");
        self.itemValue.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self.itemValue.setObjectName('itemValue_' + str(index.row()))
        self.itemValue.clicked.connect (lambda: self.directClick(index))

        self.mainlayout = QVBoxLayout ()
        self.mainlayout.addWidget(self.itemValue)
        self.mainlayout.addWidget (self.dateValue)
        editor.setLayout(self.mainlayout)
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        dateString = str(index.data())
        self.dateValue.setText(dateString)
        self.itemValue.setText('itemValue_' + str(index.row()))

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index, rps_id):
        pass

    def inputComboChanged(self):
        print("inputComboChanged:", self.inputCombo.currentIndex(), self.inputCombo.currentText())

    def directClick(self, index):
        fromObject = self.sender().objectName ()
        fromRow = fromObject.split('_')[1]
        print("directClick !!!", fromObject, fromRow)
        delegateindex = self.parent().model().index(int(fromRow),0)
        print("dindex:",delegateindex.row())

        # Does not set to position
        self.parent().setCurrentIndex (delegateindex)
        # Does not help
        self.parent().scrollTo (delegateindex)

        self.inputCombo = QComboBox ()
        self.inputCombo.addItems(['A1','A2','A3'])
        self.inputCombo.setEditable (True)
        self.inputCombo.currentIndexChanged.connect (self.inputComboChanged)
        self.mainlayout.removeWidget (self.itemValue)
        self.mainlayout.insertWidget (0, self.inputCombo, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)

class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    ActiveRole = Qt.UserRole + 1
    def __init__(self, datain, headerdata, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.arraydata = datain
        self.headerdata = headerdata

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            return QVariant(self.headerdata[section])
        return QVariant()

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid(): return 0
        return len(self.arraydata)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid(): return 0
        if len(self.arraydata) > 0:
            return len(self.arraydata[0])
        return 0

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QVariant()
        elif role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant()
        return QVariant(self.arraydata[index.row()][index.column()])

    def print_arraydata(self):
        print(self.arraydata)

    def insert_row(self, data, position, rows=1):
        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), position, position + rows - 1)
        for i, e in enumerate(data):
            self.arraydata.insert(i+position, e[:])
        self.endInsertRows()
        return True

    def remove_row(self, position, rows=1):
        self.beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), position, position + rows - 1)
        self.arraydata = self.arraydata[:position] + self.arraydata[position + rows:]
        self.endRemoveRows()
        return True

    def append_row(self, data):
        self.insert_row([data], self.rowCount())

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # create table view:
        self.tableview = self.createTable()
        # create layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.tableview)
        # initializing layout
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 500)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    def createTable(self):
        tv = QTableView()
        tv.resizeRowsToContents()
        # set header for columns:
        header = ['Name', 'Type', 'var1', 'var2', 'var3']
        tabledata = [[1,2,3,4],[11,12,13,14],[21,22,23,24],[31,32,33,34]]
        tablemodel = Model(tabledata, header, self)
        tv.setModel (tablemodel)
        for row in range (tablemodel.rowCount ()):
            tv.setRowHeight(row, 200)
        tv.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, dateDelegate2(tv))
        return tv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What's the reason for having a QLabel as an editor? Your approach seems a bit too complex, and I'm afraid you might be facing an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: My app has a 'show only' and an 'edit' mode, depending on restrictions. To avoid complaints I want to use a simple QLabel for the users and QCombo for admins. I played around with `setStyleSheet` but I found no way to totally eliminate the arrow and its background.

Comment: There various issues in your code; most importantly, using `openPersistentEditor` within the `paint()` function is just *wrong*); then, using instance attributes for an item delegate like that never works out, especially if you're using persistent editors (obviously, each `self.<object>` will always be referred to the last <object> created. Besides that, if you want to avoid users to edit the content of the table, just use `setEditTriggers` or return a flag without `Qt.ItemIsEditable` from the model's `flag()` implementation whenever you need to disable editing.

Comment: You're right. But without  `openPersistentEditor ` the combo never appears. The` flags()` are not the solution because then there are still the arrows. Maybe I will discuss this again.

Comment: Then use `openPersistentEditor` only when in "edit mode" and upon initialization of the table, certainly *not* in the `paint` method (which is called very often, and you need to open the editor only once). The flags are required if you want to avoid editing and the view has any edit trigger set.